# what is tinyurl1?

Tags: android

i m trying to run my app on my device (as emulator) and i m getting in the console a message that is installing another app too,called tinyurl1...what is this?

```
11-05-15 19:35:09 - ch] Uploading ch.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-05-15 19:35:29 - ch] Installing ch.apk...
[2011-05-15 19:35:36 - ch] Success!
[2011-05-15 19:35:37 - ch] Project dependency found, installing: tinyurl1
[2011-05-15 19:35:37 - tinyurl1] Uploading tinyurl1.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-05-15 19:35:37 - tinyurl1] Installing tinyurl1.apk...
[2011-05-15 19:35:41 - tinyurl1] Success!
```

Comment: In the setting i found it as "androidpeople.com-tinyURL"..is that a bug or something like a varius?

Comment: what is that depedency?can i stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably a reference to that APK in your Eclipse project. See [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html) of the dev guide.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [android-tinyurl  project page](http://code.google.com/p/android-tinyurl/)?

Comment: no!my question is why my app installing this "depedency" app!i havent see something like that before...and i dont know how to fix it